# How to get all nested content from IContent?

Tags: c#, episerver

Is there any way to get all the nested media files from the *IContent* object? I've attached to *publishing content* event and I want to know when any of the *MediaType* is being published. For instance, we may have a page, containing blocks with *ContentArea* and assets. How can I get all children content?

Comment: If you check in publishing event `if (e.Content is MediaData) { ... }` then you'll handle publish for all medias - is that what you need?

Comment: I would like to get all the media files from published page or block. For example, event is fired for a published page, but this page might contain nested media files. So I somehow want to search/traverse an *IContent* object in recursive way and get all the nested files.

Comment: that is a non-trivial task, and no standard way to do that in EPiSerevr; consider reviewing your logic to do that in another way (use EPiServer Find for example, or check if soft links can help you); custom code would be to go through all the properties collection, and for each property type find references to content, and for each found content recursively repeat; you will need custom processing at least for LinkCollection, ContentArea, XHTML, and any custom properties you have

Comment: What are you actaully trying to achive? Maybe there is a better and easier solution?

Comment: I use external content provider and I want to keep track of used media files. So, when someone decide to use a file and publish on the page I want to be informed about it. I thought it will be easier to traverse content of the published page but it seems that it is going to be more complex task.